# Laravel fetch array of arrays with groupBy

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a Laravel table `posts` with multiple `categories`. How can I fetch all the `posts` grouped by `categories`? I was doing something like `Post::where('userID', 1)->groupBy('categoryID')`. But this only returned a flat array of named arrays like this:

```
[1 => ['title'=>'title 1'], 2 => ['title'=>'title3']]
```

How can I return an array of arrays like this:

```
[1 => [['title'=>'title 1'], ['title' => 'title 2], 2 => [['title'=>'title 3']]]
```

UPDATE:
I'm currently doing a join and then use Laravel's collection to sort it in php:

```
   Post::join('categories', ....).where('userID', 1)->get()->groupBy('categoryID');
```

I am able to get what I want, but wondering if there is a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want this:

```
$catsWithPosts = Category::with(array('posts' => function($query){
    $query->select('title')->where('userID', 1);
}))->get();
```

Assumed that, you have declared proper relationship between `Post` and `Category` model.

Comment: Thanks, but the `userID` is on `posts`. This seems to be not working.

Comment: Which table contains category_id ?

Comment: This seems to work. But looking at the documentation, I'm wondering if I'm doing n queries depending on my categories count? http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent

Comment: No, it's not `n+` queries because it's using eager loading technique.